# Bootstrap site, not mobile friendly anymore

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

I made a website with Ubercart and Bootstrap. It was all running fine until a while ago. For some reason the website stopped being mobile friendly. When on mobiles it would show the desktop version and the navigation bar would not become the three bars button for example. Weird thing is when resizing the browser window on the computer it works as expected, but when trying it in developer tools it just doesn't care and remains as desktop version, on mobiles as well. I'm pulling my hair at this point. I have tried disabling a ton of modules but nothing changed. If you can look at the website and go into developer tools and check if there is some sort of an error or something that could help.

Comment: You're loading Bootstrap JS twice somehow. Once from your site and once from a CDN. https://i.imgur.com/6eczRAq.png In your theme's .info file, remove the one on your site and see what happens. For some reason, it is shown as "plain" in that screenshot whereas in my sites, it has "js". Btw, it's mobile friendly in Firefox inspector.

Comment: Also, your bootstrap divs don't really follow convention. You're missing lots of containers and rows. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Hi @NiallMurphy Thanks for your input. The JS loading from my website is for a workaround in order to get the navbar lists to expand on mouse hover rather than click, I tried removing that and nothing changed. I will be looking into the bootstrap divs problem that you mentioned. If you can elaborate on that one further that would be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is missing from your <head>. If you add that in Inspector, responsiveness comes back.

Comment: Wow that's actually correct. No idea how such a tag that should have been automatically generated was not being generated anymore. Fixed it. Please provide that as an answer so I can pick it as answer. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your page's `<head>`, somehow the viewport got removed.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Without this, Bootstrap in general and `@media` in bootstrap.css don't know what width the screen is initially.

This should generally be auto-generated or put into `html.tpl.php`.

Comment: Thank you very much man. Would not have thought about checking something that should have been auto generated.

Comment: Yeah, a bit of a lucky find. I realised something was wrong with the width when your bootstrap columns were using `@media (min-width: 992px)` when the screen width I had was like 300px. I had a couple of issues a long time ago with the viewport so happened to remember.